# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0, not self coding a program

Tags: python, pytorch, stable-diffusion

I'm at the end of my rope. I don't know anything about coding, I don't know how to fix this, I'm not even trying to code a program, and I am getting this while trying to create a token using automatic1111's textual inversion method. Not training it, mind you, just creating the token. The full error looks like this:

> File
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\routes.py",
> line 275, in run_predictoutput = await app.blocks.process_api(File
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py",
> line 787, in process_apiresult = await self.call_function(fn_index,
> inputs, iterator)File
>
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py",
> line 694, in call_functionprediction = await
> anyio.to_thread.run_sync(File
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py",
> line 31, in run_syncreturn await
> get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(File
>
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio_backends_asyncio.py",
> line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_threadreturn await futureFile
>
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio_backends_asyncio.py",
> line 867, in runresult = context.run(func, *args)File
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\textual_inversion\ui.py",
> line 11, in create_embeddingfilename =
> modules.textual_inversion.textual_inversion.create_embedding(name,
> nvpt, init_text=initialization_text)File
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\textual_inversion\textual_inversion.py",
> line 161, in create_embeddingembedded =
> embedding_layer.token_embedding.wrapped(ids.to(devices.device)).squeeze(0)File
>
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py",
> line 1130, in _call_implreturn forward_call(*input, **kwargs)File
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\sparse.py",
> line 158, in forwardreturn F.embedding(File
> "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\AutomaticWebUI\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py",
> line 2199, in embeddingreturn torch.embedding(weight, input,
> padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
>
> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found
> at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for
> argument index in method wrapper__index_select)

I don't know what to do. Here's everything I've tried so far:

1. entirely reinstalled the automatic repo from scratch
2. deleted everything mentioning 'cuda' on my c drive
3. reinstalling my graphics drivers
4. uninstalling and reinstalling python and git
5. uninstalling the cuda thing I installed originally as well as everything else it installed

I got rid of tensorflow as well, there is no cudatoolkit installed anymore, and somehow it still thinks I have 2 cpus or whatever this means, and I seriously don't want to have to nuke my harddrive and go back to factory settings over this. All of this started because I was trying to get deepdanbooru's interrogator to work on my gpu, and that required me to use this: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

and somehow in the process of doing that I've basically bricked it and I'm just overwhelmed and in over my head, and I have 0 idea of what to do beyond this, because I don't know how I convinced it that I have something called cuda:0 on my pc, when there is no file or any directory or anything installed with that name.

I only have 1 cpu and 1 gpu. I don't know how to convince it that whatever this cuda:0 is is not something that exists as far as I know, and I don't know how to remove it.

If anyone could tell me how to do that so I don't have to entirely wipe my hard drive, that would be great. And please explain in the simplest terms, because I'm autistic and I know nothing about python coding.

Please help.

Comment: This is a problem in the code, none of the things you tried would fix the code, if you don't know any programming, you are not the person to fix this, I suggest that you submit a issue to the repo so the authors can fix it.

Comment: And note that cuda:0 is just a pytorch way to refer to your GPU, it is not a device you installed or anything like that.

Comment: If you can, I'd suggest you install the project inside a anaconda environment: https://www.anaconda.com/ and install pytorch as suggested here: https://pytorch.org/ into that environment. That avoids issues between dependencies of different projects.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy okay but this didn't happen until I installed the nvidia cuda package, which was a mistake, and it worked before. Is it possible to undo whatever I did? I'm pretty sure I messed up at step 4 of the link I posted, but I can't figure out how to undo that.

Comment: @cherrywoods I tried that originally and had more issues where it wouldn't download the right dependencies; is there more of a benefit to doing that over just using git bash to download it?

Comment: Yes, it provides you with a virtual environment. Keeps project separate from each other. Avoids collisions of dependencies of different projects.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution! It isn't actually a flaw in their code, it's a mix of user error and my lack of knowledge as to how the code works.

Here's the solution, in case anyone else is like me and screws this up.

When I reinstalled this via the git bash, I edited the .bat file with --medvram as the guide recommended.

HOWEVER. Apparently, adding this command entirely confuses it. Removing the --medvram command fixes the problem.

Comment: This literally means there are flaws in the code :)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy okay yes, that is technically true. I meant that the fault wasn't them, it was me, their code works fine I just didn't realize that this edit that was in the guide to supposedly make it work better suddenly convinced it I had some other gpu.